# Ratio of 9th grade students to 10th grade students

Tags: contest-math

I've been pondering on this question and I realize my understanding of percentages are probably weak so please help guide me through. Let's say 9th grade is 70% girls and tenth grade is 30% girls. If 40% of all ninth and tenth grade students are girls, what is the ratio of the number of 9th grade students to 10th grade students.
So this is from my understanding: I think 70 out of 100 students are girls in gr 9, and 30 out of 100 girls in gr 10. Then this means total number of students in gr 9 and 10 would be 200 so 40% of that is 80 students. But I don't know where to go from here and I feel like it doesn't add up...Please explain what is wrong with my thinking and how I should be thinking! Thank you!!

Comment: Percentages like 40% here _can_ represent things like 40 out of 100. But they don't always _have_ to - notice that 20 out of 50 is also "40%". So there's no reason why total number of students in each year has to be 100! In fact, it turns out that both _aren't_ 100 (if you work through the problem, you'll find that the ratio is not 1, so the number of students in each year is not equal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your answer is that you're implicitly assuming the ratio of students in the two classes to be $1:1$. (Are you able to see that?)

Here's how to go about it:

Let the number of students in $9^{th}$ grade be $x$ and $10^{th}$ grade be $y$.

$$G_9 = 0.7x$$

$$G_{10} = 0.3y$$

$$G = G_9 + G_{10} = 0.4(x+y)$$

Notation:

$G_9$: girls in $9^{th}$ grade.

$G_{10}$: girls in $10^{th}$ grade.

$G$: Total girls

Solve for $\frac{x}{y}$!

Comment: Added a few lines on where you're going wrong with your solution.

Comment: Ohh I see, I actually did do it this way but thought I couldn't solve it. But I see it now! Thank you!

Comment: Sure. No problem. Plz mark the answer accepted if there are no further queries.

Comment: @StarS After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Got it, thank you for letting me know!! :)